# HandlerInterceptorAdapter - Set Request Header

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

I want to override one of the HTTP Headers as soon as I get the request from the consumer. I have a class that extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter  where I intercept the HTTP request. Is there a way to override the one of the header values inside the below listed method?

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

}
```

Comment: No, you can't. The `HttpServletRequest` interface does not expose any way to change the headers. Use a `Filter` and wrap the `HttpServletRequest` with something that intercepts the `getHeader` call and returns whatever you want it to return.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios. Is there a recommended way of defining a filter in a spring boot app?

Comment: I don't know spring boot very well. I would imagine you just define a `@Bean` for your `Filter`.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios , I'll try that!